# How to extract digits from a URL and save them in a variable?

Tags: regex, perl, nginx, pcre

I have a forwarding request which involves a bunch of products with production ID.

```
http://www.example.com/abc/en_us/Products/Cards/Note-Cards/Laser-Note-Cards_05315.htm
```

to

```
 www.example.com/products/cards/05315
```

So I want to make a regex pattern to match the four or five digit product ID in the original URL and use a variable to save it. Then we can reuse that variable to build the destination link.

I have set up a rule like before, but it doesn't work. Could anybody here help me with this or give me some examples that I can imitate?

```
location ~ ^/abc/en_us/(?<myvar>[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]) {
 # use variable $myvar here
 #if ( $myvar = "sth" ) { ... }
 rewrite ^/$1/$2/$myvar;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A map is a great way to capture a variable value. It's a safe place to use a regular expression; meaning it does disrupt the natural flow of your configuration with regex locations (see: [Scaleable NGINX Configuration: Igor Sysoev @nginxconf 2014](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YWRYbLKsS0I)). The variable is set early in the request cycle and can be used throughout your config.

```
map $uri $prod_id {
    ~(?<p_id>\d+)\.htm$ $p_id;
}

server {
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 200 "Production id: $prod_id
";
}
```

So the following prefix location should work:

```
location /avery/en_us/Products/ {
    return 301 http://www.avery.com/$prod_id;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I was able to get the variable value showed by using the "return 200 "Production id: $prod_id". However, when I tried to set up the location directive, I couldn't get the forwarding work. My forwarding is like below    :

Comment: You may need to make the location more specific. My example may be too general. I've added another directory to my example prefix location, but you may need to experiment some more.

Answer (score 0):

Use this: `$myvar = $1 if $location =~ m/^abc.*(\d+).htm/;`

$1 would be the first set of digits matched right before .htm.

Answer (score 0):

You would want something like this

```
server {
    listen 80; 
    server_name www.example.com;
    rewrite ^/abc/en_us/Products/Cards/Note-Cards/Laser-Note-Cards_([0-9]+).htm /products/cards/$1 last;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could I use some parameter or wildcards to replace "Cards", "Note-cards" and the strings before those numbers? The reason for this is we have different products categories which compose the product link. One example would be /abc/en_us/Products/binder/single-binder/XXX-12345.htm.

Answer (score 0):

```
Finally, I got it working by using "mapping" and regex with if. Thanks for all the help. 

First, define the variale from the URL. 
map $uri $prod_id {
      ~(?<p_id>\d+)\.htm$ $p_id;
 }

Second, make rewrite rule based on if statement. 
if ($uri ~ "^/avery/en_us/Products/([0-9a-zA-Z-_]*)/([0-9a-zA-Z-_]*)/([0-9a-
 zA-Z-_.]*).htm$") {
             rewrite ^/avery/en_us/Products/([0-9a-zA-Z-_]*)/([0-9a-zA-Z-
 _]*)/([0-9a-zA-Z-_.]*).htm$ http://www.avery.com/$prod_id permanent;
    }
```